Is the memory allocation of this char ** and the subsequent allocation of char * correct?
I have the following struct definition intended to represent a time series chart:
/* MAX TICKS 24 HOURS * 60 MIN * 60 SEC */
#define MAX_TICKS 86400

/* CHART PARAMETERS */
typedef struct {

    /* DRAWING AREA WIDGET */
    Widget drawingArea;

    /* X-AXIS (TIME) */
    int x_tick_spacing_px;                  /* DISTANCE BETWEEN TIME TICKS IN PIXELS. */
    int x_num_ticks;                        /* TOTAL NUMBER OF TIME TICKS. */
    int *x_tick_values;                     /* ARRAY OF TIME TICK VALUES (E.G., 093000 FOR 09:30:00). */
    char **x_tick_labels;                   /* ARRAY OF TIME TICK LABELS, CORRESPONDING TO X_TICK_VALUES. */


} TSChart;

And I am writing a parser to handle commands defining the xaxis definition:
/* FUNCTION TO PARSE AND EXECUTE COMMANDS */
void parse_command(TSChart *chartData, char *command) {
    
    int arg_count;
    char **args;
    char *token;

    /* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR ARGS */
    args = malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(char *));
    if (args == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for args.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* INITIALIZE ARGUMENT COUNT TO ZERO */
    arg_count = 0;

    /* TOKENIZE THE COMMAND */
    token = strtok(command, " ");
    while (token != NULL && arg_count < MAX_ARGS) {
        args[arg_count++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    /* COMMAND PARSING */
    if (arg_count == 0) return;

    if(strcmp(args[0], "xaxis") == 0) { xaxis_command(chartData, arg_count - 1, args + 1); return; }

    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN COMMAND.\n");

    /* FREE THE ARGS ARRAY */
    free(args);
}

/* FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE "XAXIS" COMMAND */
void xaxis_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args) {
    
    int i;    
    int spacing;                /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE SPACE BETWEEN TICKS IN PIXELS */
    int num_values;             /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE THE NUMBER OF VALUES PASSED */
    int num_labels;             /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE THE NUMBER OF LABELS PASSED */

    if (arg_count < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS COMMAND EXPECTS AT LEAST 2 ARGUMENTS.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* SPACING */
    if (strcmp(args[0], "spacing") == 0) {
        if (arg_count != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS SPACING EXPECTS 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (sscanf(args[1], "%d", &spacing) == 1) {
            chartData->x_tick_spacing_px = spacing;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID SPACING VALUE.\n");
        }
        return;
    } 

    /* VALUES */
    if (strcmp(args[0], "values") == 0) {
        if (arg_count < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS VALUES EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        num_values = atoi(args[1]);
        if (num_values != arg_count - 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF VALUES DOES NOT MATCH EXPECTED COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (num_values > MAX_TICKS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF VALUES EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        chartData->x_num_ticks = num_values;
        chartData->x_tick_values = (int *)malloc(num_values * sizeof(unsigned int));
        if (chartData->x_tick_values == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR X TICK VALUES.\n");
            return;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < num_values; i++) {
            chartData->x_tick_values[i] = atoi(args[i + 2]);
        }
        return;
    } 

    /* LABELS */
    if (strcmp(args[0], "labels") == 0) {
        if (arg_count < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS LABELS EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        num_labels = atoi(args[1]);
        if (num_labels != arg_count - 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF LABELS DOES NOT MATCH EXPECTED COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (num_labels > MAX_TICKS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF LABELS EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        chartData->x_num_ticks = num_labels;
        chartData->x_tick_labels = (char **)malloc(num_labels * sizeof(char *));
        if (chartData->x_tick_labels == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR X TICK LABELS.\n");
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < num_labels; i++) {
            if(strcmp(args[i + 2], "_")==0) {
                chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = NULL;
            } else {
                chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = strdup(args[i + 2]);
            }
        }
        return;
    } 

    /* UNKNOWN SUBCOMMAND */
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN XAXIS SUBCOMMAND.\n");
    
}


The subcommand to set up x_tick_spacing_px and int *x_tick_values work fine.
However setting char **x_tick_labels causes an "Abort trap" -providing no further details-
Is the allocation of memory for char **x_tick_labels and the subsequent allocation of individual strings properly done?
SECOND EDIT/EXAMPLE:

I have corrected as per comments the allocation of the individual strings:
/* FUNCTION TO PARSE AND EXECUTE COMMANDS */
void parse_command(TSChart *chartData, char *command) {

    int i;  
    int arg_count;
    char **args;
    char *token;
    
    /* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR ARGS */
    args = (char **)malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(char *));
    if (args == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for args.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* INITIALIZE ARGUMENT COUNT TO ZERO */
    arg_count = 0;

    /* TOKENIZE THE COMMAND */
    token = strtok(command, " ");
    while (token != NULL && arg_count < MAX_ARGS) {
        args[arg_count] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG cli.c arg_count %d token %s\n", arg_count, token);
        arg_count++;
    }

    /* COMMAND PARSING */
    if (arg_count == 0) return;

    if(strcmp(args[0], "redraw") == 0) redraw_command(chartData); 
    else if(strcmp(args[0], "line") == 0) line_command(chartData, arg_count, args); 
    else if(strcmp(args[0], "xaxis") == 0) xaxis_command(chartData, arg_count, args); 
    else fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN COMMAND.\n");

    /* FREE THE ARGS ARRAY */
    for(i=0; i<arg_count; i++) free(args[i]);
    free(args);
}

I also include the function processing the command itself:

/* FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE "XTICK" COMMAND */
void xaxis_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args) {
    
    int i;    
    int spacing;                /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE SPACE BETWEEN TICKS IN PIXELS */
    int num_values;             /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE THE NUMBER OF VALUES PASSED */
    int num_labels;             /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE THE NUMBER OF LABELS PASSED */

    if (arg_count < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: xaxis COMMAND EXPECTS AT LEAST 2 ARGUMENTS.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* SPACING */
    if (strcmp(args[1], "spacing") == 0) {
        if (arg_count != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: xaxis spacing EXPECTS 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (sscanf(args[2], "%d", &spacing) == 1) {
            chartData->x_tick_spacing_px = spacing;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID SPACING VALUE.\n");
        }
        return;
    } 

    /* VALUES */
    if (strcmp(args[1], "values") == 0) {
        if (arg_count < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: xaxis values EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        num_values = atoi(args[2]);
        if (num_values != arg_count - 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF VALUES DOES NOT MATCH EXPECTED COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (num_values > MAX_TICKS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF VALUES EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        chartData->x_num_ticks = num_values;
        chartData->x_tick_values = (int *)malloc(num_values * sizeof(unsigned int));
        if (chartData->x_tick_values == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR X TICK VALUES.\n");
            return;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < num_values; i++) {
            chartData->x_tick_values[i] = atoi(args[i + 3]);
        }
        return;
    } 

    /* LABELS */
    if (strcmp(args[1], "labels") == 0) {
        if (arg_count < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: xaxis labels EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
            return;
        }
        num_labels = atoi(args[2]);
        if (num_labels != arg_count - 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF LABELS DOES NOT MATCH EXPECTED COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        if (num_labels > MAX_TICKS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF LABELS EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
            return;
        }
        chartData->x_num_ticks = num_labels;
        fprintf(stderr, "num_labels %d\n", num_labels);
        chartData->x_tick_labels = (char **)malloc(num_labels * sizeof(char *));
        if (chartData->x_tick_labels == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR X TICK LABELS.\n");
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < num_labels; i++) {
            if(strcmp(args[i + 3], "_")==0) {
                chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = NULL;
            } else {
                chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = strdup(args[i + 3]);
            }
        }
        goto DEBUG;
        return;
    } 

    /* UNKNOWN SUBCOMMAND */
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN xaxis SUBCOMMAND.\n");
   
DEBUG: 
    fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG cli.c xaxis_command() | chartData->x_num_ticks %d\n", chartData->x_num_ticks);
    fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG cli.c xaxis_command() | chartData->x_tick_labels %p\n", chartData->x_tick_labels);
    for(i=0; i<chartData->x_num_ticks; i++) {
        if(chartData->x_tick_labels[i] != NULL) fprintf(stderr,"x_tick_labels[%d] = #%s#\n", i, chartData->x_tick_labels[i]);
    }
}

Yet still the same Abort trap. The procedure is completed correctly and no reading of the involved struct is performed before the Abort trap message appears.
THIRD EDIT/EXAMPLE:

I have prepared a reproducible example. Among the different things I have tried: I have tried removing strtok and preallocating arrays in the struct. It seems the problem was not there but elsewhere, as shown in this new reproducible example.
There are 4 source files and 1 makefile which I include. The main source file tschart.c can be easily fixed to test directly calling the parse_command instead of initiating the Xt loop. When that is done, everything works as expected. However, when the command string is provided via an XtTextField using an Xt Callback I get an AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL. This is consistent with the original reported issue.
tschart.c
#include <Xm/Xm.h>
#include <Xm/Form.h>
#include <Xm/PushB.h>
#include <Xm/TextF.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tschart.h"
#include "cli.h"

Widget toplevel;
XtAppContext appContext;

static void submit_command_callback(Widget widget, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    TSChart *chartData;

    int i;
    int n;
    Arg args[20];

    Widget mainWindow;
    Widget commandTextField;
    Widget submitButton;

    /* INITIALIZE THE APPLICATION AND CREATE THE TOP-LEVEL SHELL */
    n = 0;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNwidth, 400); n++;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNheight, 300); n++;
    toplevel = XtAppInitialize(&appContext, "Xtschart", NULL, 0, &argc, argv, NULL, args, n);


    /* CREATE THE MAIN WINDOW WIDGET */
    n = 0;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNresizePolicy, False); n++;
    mainWindow = XtCreateWidget("mainWindow", xmFormWidgetClass, toplevel, args, n);

    /* CREATE INPUT COMMAND AREA */
    n = 0;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNtopAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); n++;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNleftAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); n++;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNrightAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); n++;
    commandTextField = XmCreateTextField(mainWindow, "commandTextField", args, n);

    /* CREATE SUBMIT BUTTON */
    n = 0;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNtopAttachment, XmATTACH_WIDGET); n++;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNtopWidget, commandTextField); n++;
    XtSetArg(args[n], XmNleftAttachment, XmATTACH_FORM); n++;
    submitButton = XmCreatePushButton(mainWindow, "EXECUTE", args, n);
    
    /* INSTANTIATE THE TS CHART STRUCT */
    chartData = (TSChart *)malloc(sizeof(TSChart));
    if (chartData == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR tschart.c main() | Memory allocation failed for chartData.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    chartData->x_tick_spacing_px = 10;
    chartData->x_num_ticks = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_TICKS; i++) {
        chartData->x_tick_values[i] = 0;
        chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = NULL;
    }

    /* ADD CALLBACK FUNCTIONS */
    XtVaSetValues(submitButton, XmNuserData, commandTextField, NULL);
    XtAddCallback(submitButton, XmNactivateCallback, submit_command_callback, chartData);

    /* MANAGE COMMAND AREA */
    XtManageChild(commandTextField);
    XtManageChild(submitButton);
    XtManageChild(mainWindow);

    /* REALIZE TOP LEVEL */ 
    XtRealizeWidget(toplevel);
    
    /* TEST DIRECT CALL AND EXIT UNCOMMENT THIS LINE AND COMMENT OUT XtAppMainLoop FOR THIS TEST */
    //parse_command(chartData, "xaxis labels 3 1 2 3"); 
    
    /* MAIN LOOP */
    XtAppMainLoop(appContext);

}
    

/* CALLBACK FUNCTION FOR THE SUBMIT BUTTON */
void submit_command_callback(Widget widget, XtPointer client_data, XtPointer call_data) {
    
    TSChart *chartData;
    Widget textField;
    char *command;
    
    /* RETRIEVE WIDGET AND CHART DATA */
    chartData = (TSChart *)call_data;
    XtVaGetValues(widget, XmNuserData, &textField, NULL);

    /* RETRIEVE COMMAND LINE */
    command = XmTextFieldGetString(textField);
    fprintf(stderr, "command #%s#\n", command);

    /* PARSE COMMAND */
    parse_command(chartData, command); /* PASS THE ADDRESS OF CHARTDATA */

    /* FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY */
    XtFree(command);
    
    /* CLEAR THE TEXT FIELD */
    XmTextFieldSetString(textField, "");
    
}

tschart.h
#ifndef _TS_CHART_WIDGET_H
#define _TS_CHART_WIDGET_H

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>

/* MAX TICKS 24 HOURS * 60 MIN * 60 SEC */
#define MAX_TICKS 86400

/* CHART PARAMETERS */
typedef struct {

    /* X-AXIS (TIME) */
    int x_tick_spacing_px;                              /* DISTANCE BETWEEN TIME TICKS IN PIXELS. */
    int x_num_ticks;                                    /* TOTAL NUMBER OF TIME TICKS. */
    int x_tick_values[MAX_TICKS];                       /* ARRAY OF TIME TICK VALUES (E.G., 093000 FOR 09:30:00). */
    char *x_tick_labels[MAX_TICKS];                     /* ARRAY OF TIME TICK LABELS, CORRESPONDING TO X_TICK_VALUES. */

} TSChart;

#endif /* _TS_CHART_WIDGET_H */ 

cli.c
#include <Xm/Xm.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cli.h"
#include "tschart.h"

/* FUNCTION TO PARSE AND EXECUTE COMMANDS */
void parse_command(TSChart *chartData, char *command) {

    int i;
    int arg_count;
    char **args;
    char *start;
    char *end;
   
    /* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR ARGS */ 
    args = (char **)malloc(MAX_ARGS * sizeof(char *));
    if (args == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for args.\n");
        return;
    }

    /* BEGIN WITH ZERO ARGUMENTS */
    arg_count = 0;
    start = command;

    /* PARSE TOKEN BY TOKEN */
    while (*start && arg_count < MAX_ARGS) {

        /* SKIP LEADING SPACES AND TABS */
        while (*start == ' ' || *start == '\t') start++;
        if (*start == '\0') break;

        /* FIND THE END OF THE TOKEN */
        end = start;
        while (*end != ' ' && *end != '\t' && *end != '\0') end++;

        /* ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR THE TOKEN AND COPY IT */
        args[arg_count] = (char *)malloc((end - start + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (args[arg_count] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for token.\n");
            break;
        }
        memcpy(args[arg_count], start, end - start);
        args[arg_count][end - start] = '\0';
        arg_count++;

        /* MOVE TO THE NEXT TOKEN */
        start = end;

    }

    /* COMMAND PARSING */
    if (arg_count == 0) return;
    for(i=0; i<arg_count; i++) fprintf(stderr, "args[%d] = #%s#\n", i, args[i]);

    if(strcmp(args[0], "xaxis") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "spacing") == 0) {
        xaxis_space_command(chartData, arg_count, args); 
    }
    else if(strcmp(args[0], "xaxis") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "values") == 0) {
        xaxis_values_command(chartData, arg_count, args); 
    }
    else if(strcmp(args[0], "xaxis") == 0 && strcmp(args[1], "labels") == 0) {
        xaxis_labels_command(chartData, arg_count, args); 
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN COMMAND.\n");

    /* FREE MEMORY */
    for(i=0; i<arg_count; i++) free(args[i]);
    free(args);

}

/* FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE "XTICK SPACE" COMMAND */
void xaxis_space_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args) {
    
    int spacing;        /* TEMPORARY VARIABLE TO STORE SPACE BETWEEN TICKS IN PIXELS */

    if (arg_count != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: xaxis spacing COMMAND REQUIRES 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
        return;
    }

    if (sscanf(args[2], "%d", &spacing) == 1) {
        chartData->x_tick_spacing_px = spacing;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: INVALID SPACE VALUE.\n");
    }

}

/* FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE "XTICK VALUES" COMMAND */
void xaxis_values_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args) {
    
    int i;
    int num_values;

    fprintf(stderr, "values coomand\n");
    for(i=0; i<arg_count; i++) fprintf(stderr, "args[%d] = #%s#\n", i, args[i]);


    if (arg_count < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS VALUES EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
        return;
    }

    num_values = atoi(args[2]);
    if (num_values > MAX_TICKS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF VALUES EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
        return;
    }
    chartData->x_num_ticks = num_values;

    fprintf(stderr, "num_values %d\n", num_values);
    for (i = 0; i < num_values; i++) {
        chartData->x_tick_values[i] = atoi(args[i + 3]);
    }
    
} 

/* FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE "XTICK LABELS" COMMAND */
void xaxis_labels_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args) {

    int i;
    int num_labels;

    if (arg_count < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: XAXIS LABELS EXPECTS AT LEAST 1 ARGUMENT.\n");
        return;
    }
    
    num_labels = atoi(args[2]);
    if (num_labels > MAX_TICKS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: NUMBER OF LABELS EXCEED MAXIMUM COUNT.\n");
        return;
    }
    chartData->x_num_ticks = num_labels;

    fprintf(stderr, "num_labels %d\n", num_labels);
    for (i = 0; i < num_labels; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "i %d args[i +3] %s\n", i, args[i+3]);
        if(strcmp(args[i + 3], "_")==0) {
            chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = NULL;
        } else {
            chartData->x_tick_labels[i] = strdup(args[i + 3]);
        }
    }
    
} 

cli.h
#ifndef _CLI_H
#define _CLI_H

#include "tschart.h"

#define MAX_ARGS 100000

void parse_command(TSChart *chartData, char *command);
void xaxis_space_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args);
void xaxis_values_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args);
void xaxis_labels_command(TSChart *chartData, int arg_count, char **args);

#endif /* _CLI_H */

makefile
# Compiler
CC = cc

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS = -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -I/usr/local/include -fsanitize=address,undefined -Og -g3

# Libraries for X11 and Motif
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -lXm -lXt -lX11 -lXmu 

# Target executable
TARGET = tschart

# Source files
SRC =   tschart.c cli.c 

# Object files
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

# Build rule
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

# Compile each .c file into .o
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Clean rule
clean:
        rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

Output when parse_command is called directly:
This works as expected:
$ ./tschart
args[0] = #xaxis#
args[1] = #labels#
args[2] = #3#
args[3] = #1#
args[4] = #2#
args[5] = #3#
num_labels 3
i 0 args[i +3] 1
i 1 args[i +3] 2
i 2 args[i +3] 3

Output when command comes from the XtTextField:

$ ./tschart
command #xaxis labels 3 1 2 3#
args[0] = #xaxis#
args[1] = #labels#
args[2] = #3#
args[3] = #1#
args[4] = #2#
args[5] = #3#
num_labels 3
i 0 args[i +3] 1
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==25973==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x50000000a4e7 (pc 0x0000002fcf5a bp 0x7fffffffdfb0 sp 0x7fffffffdf50 T0)
==25973==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x2fcf5a in xaxis_labels_command /home/user/cli.c:148:32
    #1 0x2fc27c in parse_command /home/user/cli.c:67:3
    #2 0x2fb9be in submit_command_callback /home/user/tschart.c:105:5
    #3 0x80063e896 in XtCallCallbackList (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x22896)
    #4 0x8004878b1  (/usr/local/lib/libXm.so.4+0x1408b1)
    #5 0x80067955f  (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x5d55f)
    #6 0x80067700e in _XtTranslateEvent (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x5b00e)
    #7 0x80064da84 in XtDispatchEventToWidget (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x31a84)
    #8 0x80064e2c3  (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x322c3)
    #9 0x80064de13 in XtDispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x31e13)
    #10 0x80065a439 in XtAppProcessEvent (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x3e439)
    #11 0x80064e637 in XtAppMainLoop (/usr/local/lib/libXt.so.6+0x32637)
    #12 0x2fb516 in main /home/user/tschart.c:84:5
    #13 0x800910a69 in __libc_start1 (/lib/libc.so.7+0x85a69)
    #14 0x24dcef in _start /usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1_s.S:83
    #15 0x800328007  (<unknown module>)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/user/cli.c:148:32 in xaxis_labels_command
==25973==ABORTING

It is worth to mention that the other commands (for instance, xaxis values 3 1 2 3) work as expected. So it might be something wrong while allocating the strings in xaxis labels that only arises when you integrate the parsing with X11/Xt/Motif where there are more components allocated into memory.
I am compiling this in FreeBSD, in case this is relevant.

No it is not correct. token = strtok(NULL, " "); instead needs a copy of the string.  Maintain those strings later free them.  "and the subsequent allocation of individual strings properly done" --> code does no "allocation of individual strings".

Detail: char **x_tick_labels; /* ARRAY OF TIME TICK LABELS, CORRESPONDING TO X_TICK_VALUES. */ is mis-commented.  x_tick_labels is a pointer, not an array.  chartData->x_tick_labels = (char **)malloc(num_labels * sizeof(char *)); allocates for that pointer, yet remains a pointer.
`

I have duplicated the string and then I free them args[arg_count] = strdup(token); but I still get the Abort trap. This is so localized with this particular sub command that I suspect it is related to the char **. Other commands populating int * work fine.

Minor: Note that chartData->x_tick_values = (int *)malloc(num_values * sizeof(unsigned int)); uses the wrong type and cast needlessly - although I doubt that is code's major problem..  chartData->x_tick_values = malloc(sizeof chartData->x_tick_values[0] * num_values); is easier to code right, review and maintain.

fixed but as you point it out does not change a thing, both types have same size.

Consider a [mcve] with posted input.  Tip: try compiling what is posted.

As no answer has been posted yet, it's fine to edit the posted code without keeping the original code. So delete the original code so it's clear which code your question is about. Having two versions just makes the question more confusing. But remember - once an answer is posted, significant changes to a question shall be avoided.

Where do you allocate memory for chartData? The problem you describe would happen if that pointer doesn't point at allocated memory.

@4386427 There are strdup calls so that part looks ok.

@Lundin Got it... I was confused by the question having two versions.

Why do you stipulate a 35-year-old standard (C89)?  You should be learning at least C99 and there's not a lot of excuse for not learning C17 (which is mostly the same as C11).  C23 is a big change from C11/C17 in some respects, though most good C11 code compiles well under C23, too.

@chux I am preparing a full reproducible example. I begin to think that the issue is not in this code but in that somehow it interacts with the fact that this program runs within an Xt/Motif application. I am wondering if I shall remove the previous two versions of my question or add another answer or do something else, since I have to paste 4 source files to get a reproducible example.

I have even tried to avoid entirely the usage of strtok and implemented my own tokenizer.

@M.E. Instead of your own tokenizer for  strtok(), consider strcspn(), strspn().

Thanks @chux, but the issue does not seem to be in the tokenizer. I am aware that strtok is not recommended anymore but not dealing with that right now. I have included a third example although I understand the original post has changed quite a bit.

@M.E. If submit_command_callback() calls (line #105) are commented out, does unexplained failure occur?

@chux, if you comment out submit_command_callback() line #105 then it does not fail. The program works as expected (it obviously does not parse anything). The XtTextField is emptied and ready for next command.

@chux it is worth to mention that xaxis values 3 1 2 3 works perfectly. the issue is when using xaxis labels 3 1 2 3. Note the later involves strings and the former ints.

Your second version has this check: if (num_labels != arg_count - 3) { but that's gone in version 3. Why? Not having that check, opens for new possible errors.

As I am struggling to find what is happening I have refactored the entire third example to see if rewriting from scratch might help. Now I am passing all arguments to the functions parsing the commands. Before I was passing just the non parsed arguments. That is why the differences. Maybe those checks should be removed as they are non relevant to the issue

This answer refers to the second block of posted code in the question.

Is the allocation of memory for char **x_tick_labels and the subsequent allocation of individual strings properly done?

Yes, it looks correct. There is no obvious error in your allocations/frees.
But there are some other problems with your code.
#1:
In this part
while (token != NULL && arg_count < MAX_ARGS) {
    args[arg_count] = strdup(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG cli.c arg_count %d token %s\n", arg_count, token);
    arg_count++;
}

fprintf is called after updating the token.
#2:
In this part
/* UNKNOWN SUBCOMMAND */
fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: UNKNOWN XTICK SUBCOMMAND.\n");


DEBUG: 
    fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG cli.c xaxis_command() | chartData->x_num_ticks %d\n", chartData->x_num_ticks);

a return is missing. Without that you start using uninitialized variables.
#3:
In this part
    args[arg_count] = strdup(token);

there is no check for strdup returning NULL so args[arg_count] may get the value NULL. The code that follows uses args in ways that can't accept a NULL. So either you need a NULL check here or the following code must be changed to handle a NULL.

Thanks I understand there were no safeguards there (and the misplacement of the debug trace), however it seems the issue is somewhere else -see third example-. Maybe this shall be reported in separate question or the original two edits shall be removed since the question has changed quite a bit.

I added chartData as XmNuserData instead of passing as call_data and also configured the XmTextField as static variable that can be accessed directly by the callback function and now everything works fine.
So essentially I make the Xt callbacks not receiving the widget or the struct via the callback arguments and that makes things work.
I do not consider this as a satisfactory answer though since this does not provide any explanation on why this happens.
